# How can I extract a type from a procedural macro attribute using darling?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I need to be able to extract the type DieselHandler, ideally in a way that allows for repeatable data_loader attributes for transforming against multiple types.

```
#[derive(Loadable)]
#[data_loader(handler = DieselHandler<FooLoader>)]
```

If I use `handler: syn::Type` there is the error:

> the trait bound `syn::Type: FromMeta` is not satisfied
> the trait `FromMeta` is not implemented for `syn::Type`

How can I pass in a type here and maybe even check the wrapper structure?

```
#[derive(Debug, FromDeriveInput)]
#[darling(attributes(data_loader))]
struct LoadByArgs {
  #[darling(default)]
  internal: bool,
  handler: ????,
}

#[proc_macro_derive(Loadable, attributes(data_loader))]
pub fn load_by(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
  let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

  let LoadByArgs {
    internal, handler
  } = FromDeriveInput::from_derive_input(&input).expect("can't parse attribute");

  let expanded = quote! {
      ...
  };

  proc_macro::TokenStream::from(expanded)
}
```

Comment: I haven't had much success with this without expressing the types as strings. ie `#[data_loader(handler = "DieselHandler<FooLoader>")]`. `handler` can then be a `syn::Path` in your code.

Comment: I think it's because darling hasn't been updated for a while, and this used to be a syntactic restriction.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without the quotes and ideally with a syntax like `#[data_loader(DieselHandler<FooLoader>)]`. Do you know of a darling alternative that would help here? I've never attempted to write a procedural macro before so I'm still picking things up

Comment: No I haven't seen anything. But darling really does make life a lot easier when you have attributes. It has saved me 100s of lines of very messy code.

Comment: Yes I definitely see the value and really don't want to write any of that by hand. Hopefully darling will add in support or maybe examples if already possible

Comment: Using syn::Path unblocked me.https://github.com/Bajix/deque-loader-rs/commit/b533ab35897fd48ed3ad7ab35c93e9f7dfc2adde

Answer (score 1):

`darling` requires the quotation marks when writing `#[attr(foo = "bar")]` because `syn` doesn't consider the quotation-free form to be a valid `Meta`, and the `Meta` is the basis of `darling`'s entire API.

That's consistent with `serde`, which I still view as the closest thing to a standard for proc-macro APIs in Rust.

You *can* use [`darling::util::PathList`](https://docs.rs/darling/0.13.0/darling/util/struct.PathList.html) if you want to write something like `#[data_loader(DieselHandler)]`. Technically type parameters are part of a path, so `DieselHandler<FooLoader>` *should* work on paper.